# Concat string from Enumerable results

Tags: c#, linq

How below can be achieved ?

```
string domains = String.Join(",",DomainsTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Domain").ToString()).ToArray());  
//D1,D2,D3,D4            

string orgs = String.Join(",", DomainsTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("org").ToString()).ToArray());
//O1,O2,O3,O4

var DomainOrg = domains.Zip(orgs, (first, second) => first + "|" + second); 
// i was trying to zip for this but did not get expected result, how it can be done..we can go for other option also

Expected result = D1|O1,D2|O2,D3|O3,D4|O4
```

Above expected reult should be string because i need to use split function to above expected result

Comment: Why are you joining the domains and orgs into a single string?

Comment: Orgs are mapped to domains so i want to have mapping between them as pair

Comment: Don't use two `string.Join`'s. Use only one. (Hint: Build the `Domain|org` parts/tuples within the Select clause then...)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Why are `domains` and `orgs` strings instead of string arrays (or other collections)?

Comment: My bad..it makes sense what you are saying..i should have string array instead of string.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't join the two source collections into a single string, because then `Zip()` will operate on the strings as character collections instead of string collections.

Take this simplified example:

```
var domains = new [] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4" };
var orgs = new [] { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4" };

var domainOrgs = domains.Zip(orgs, (first, second) => first + "|" + second);

var joined = string.Join(",", domainOrgs);
```

Now `joined` contains:

> D1|O1,D2|O2,D3|O3,D4|O4